# Are quantum operations reversible?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

If We perform some unitary operations on a Quantum State $|A\rangle$ after which it becomes$|A'\rangle$. Then if we perform the inverse of all those unitary operations on the state $|A'\rangle$ in reverse order, can we roll back to the state $|A\rangle$?

Comment: What you've described is the reversibility of *unitary transformations* and not the "reversibility of the state". Unitaries are invertible maps -- in fact, the set of all unitaries forms a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_group) -- and so yes, you will revert back to the original state. I'm not sure what you mean by the state being "reversible"? Do you mean invertible as a matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Any operation on quantum computer (with measurement being exception) are described by unitary matrix. A feature of the unitary matrix is $AA^\dagger=I$, which means that transpose conjugate to matrix $A$ is inverse to $A$ too. It can be easily proven that if $A$ is unitary then $A^\dagger$ is also unitary hence it is also quantum gate.

If you came from state $|\psi_0\rangle$ to $|\psi_1\rangle$ by transformation $A|\psi_0\rangle = |\psi_1\rangle$, then it is possible to reverse the transformation in this way: $A^{\dagger}|\psi_1\rangle = |\psi_0\rangle$.

In practise, this means that you put all gates in original circuit in reverse order and replace each gate $A$ with its transpose conjugate operator $A^{\dagger}$.

Comment: "Any operation on quantum computer (with measurement being exception) are described by unitary matrix". This is only true for *pure* states. The most general formulation of quantum dynamics is via CP-maps (with the states described by density matrices) and the only invertible CP maps (assuming input-output dimensions are the same) are unitaries; namely, *every* non-unitary CP map is *not* invertible. So, I would at least append the original statement.

Comment: @keisuke.akira: Thanks for the comment, however, I am a little bit confused. I said that only operation described be unitaries are reversible, others are not. The others are measurement which cannot be reversed. I seems to me that you comment says the same. Or what am I missing?

Comment: My disagreement is with the first sentence of your answer, "Any operation on quantum computer (with measurement being exception) are described by unitary matrix". This seems a bit ambiguous: I think a more precise statement would be to specify that CP maps encompass both unitaries and beyond, and are generally non-invertible -- even if we don't think of them as a (generalized) measurement.

Comment: @keisuke.akira: OK, sure. I have to say that I see quantum computing mainly from programmer (or engineer) point of view. As far as I know, any quantum gate used in gate-based models should be reversibl, however, I see that you have deeper understanding of general models of QC than I. Please feel free to edit my answer in order to be more accurate.

Comment: Your answer is correct @MartinVesely but what keisuke is trying to say is measurement can't be reversed.

Comment: @Rishwi binnu: Yes, I agree. I also said so.